# Flows stop when changing project

Tags: node-red

I use node-red to read data from different sources and afterwards write it to a database.
In order to get data in a regular time interval, e.g. every minute, I use the *cronplus node*.
Both works very fine so far.

However, now I started to organize my flows in different projects within the node-red user interface (see picture) - and I realized that data is written to the DB only of the flows of the project that was most recently loaded. That is to say that if I open a new project, all flows of the previous project are stopped (and thus no data arrives in the DB), and the flows of the newly open project are started immediately.

Is there a way that the flows are constantly working in several projects at the same time?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The runtime only runs one project at a time. You need to organise your flows inside a single project.

Comment: so what's the point of allowing different projects? but thanks anyways, good to know!

Comment: So is there one active project allowed per user? This would mean that I have to have another user account to run different projects simultanously?

Comment: No, there is one active project per runtime, adding another user will not change that

Comment: what does runtime mean in that case? Would I need to run it from a different server?

Comment: You will do better joining the Node-RED slack and having a proper discussion about what you are trying to achieve.